# Extending the search function to a specific meta field value in the admin posts table

Tags: search

I'd like to transfor the following code. This code was done to add a specific search for post ID numbers. Now I need a function to extend the search to a meta field called "function_name", and the search is not public but from the admin post table

```php
function search_by_post_id( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_search ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $query->query_vars['s'] ) ) {
            $query->set( 'post_type', 'any' );
            $query->set( 'post__in', array( (int) $query->query_vars['s'] ) );
            $query->set( 's', '' );
        }
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_by_post_id' );
```

Comment: The hook [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) is an action, not a filter: change `add_filter()` to `add_action()` and remove `return $query`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `meta_query` parameter of `WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) to search custom fields.

Untested:

```php
$meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query', array() );

$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'     => 'function_name',
    'value'   => $query->query_vars['s'],
    'compare' => 'LIKE',
);

$query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
```

Comment: I suppose I have to complete the function and start with function search_by_meta($meta_query) {

Comment: Up to you how you implement, though you'll still use the `pre_get_posts` hook, so your parameter wouldn't be `$meta_query`.